# Oracle Materialized Views and Extended Statistics (ORA-12048 error encountered while referencing materialized view)

Tags: oracle, view, oracle12c, materialized

We added a materialized view to our application to help speed up a grid that shows aggregate information. The view really improved performance dramatically, which was great. However, for some reason, Oracle (12c) creates a virtual column to one of the tables referenced in the view and breaks the view. ORA-12048 error encountered while referencing materialized view.

I understand that Oracle 12c may be creating the virtual column because of extended statistics.

What's the best solution to prevent this from happening, can extended statistics be disabled for specific tables?

Comment: First thing would be to patch up. 12c covers a huge range of versions and patches. The behaviour that was triggered to create the new virtual column was new in 12.1 and perhaps was buggy. I suspect it’s fixed now though.

Comment: Are you sure extended stats are the problem? "ORA-12048" is a generic error message, but if you look at the entire error stack there should be a more specific error message.